# How do I make an insert statment with the date in the format in MM/DD/YYYY into an oracle create table like below?

Tags: oracle

The table and statement in question are below, the date results in an error when I try enter it

```
CREATE TABLE cteam_ExpenseReport ( 
    ERNo NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    ERDesc VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,     
    ERSubmitDate DATE,
    ERStatusDate DATE ,
    ERStatus CHAR(8)NOT NULL, 
    SubmitUserNo NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    ApprUserNo NUMBER NOT NULL

);


INSERT INTO cteam_ExpenseReport 
(ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUserNo)
VALUES (1,'Sales Presentation','8/10/2002','8/26/2002','APPROVED',3,4);
```

Comment: whatever format you use for the literal, the date data type has no format, we're just trying to express as a string. So, nevermind the format conversion and use standard ANSI format such as `date'2002-10-08'` (with `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format)as @Tejash already told.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String can not be directly converted to date. You can use either `to_date` or `date` function as following:

```
INSERT INTO cteam_ExpenseReport 
(ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUserNo)
VALUES (1, 'Sales Presentation',
    TO_DATE('08/10/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
    TO_DATE('08/26/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),    
    'APPROVED', 3, 4 );
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO cteam_ExpenseReport 
    (ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUserNo)
    VALUES (1, 'Sales Presentation',
        DATE '2002-08-10',
        DATE '2002-08-26',   
        'APPROVED', 3, 4 );
```

`DATE` function accepts `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Cheers!!

Comment: You can concert a string directly to a `DATE` by relying on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. However, this is really not the recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_DATE()` to convert your string to a `DATE`:

```
INSERT INTO cteam_ExpenseReport 
(ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUserNo)
VALUES (
    1,
    'Sales Presentation',
    TO_DATE('8/10/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    TO_DATE('8/26/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    'APPROVED',
    3,
    4
);
```